# Marketing Cloud - AMPscript to validate form data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

I am wondering about missing security stuff when reading about AMPscript, Marketing Cloud and Cloud Pages.

I can setup a Cloud Page, there I write a HTML form and send it to another Cloud Page. Here I can use AMPscript to get each of the request parameter and can do some logic with it, for example InsertDE(), UpdateDE() and so on - so I can write data to the database.

Now my question: Where can I find some documentation / best practice pattern about validating this data?

Sure I can use Javascript und there some sources like jquery form validation to validate the stuff before submit - but we all know that client validation is not the most secure way to avoid injections.

I found some basic functions at the AMPscript functions list - but I think there are some things missing like escaping strings.

How do you handle this? Is there a site I missed?

Comment: How you'd handle form validation in SFMC pages isn't really any different than any other server-side language.  You can get all of the form values with AMPScript in the POST and do whatever you need to do with string functions.  Did you have some specific scenario that you think isn't covered?